# QGIS - cannot open certain WUI files for a hazard map

Tags: qgis, shapefile, esri-geodatabase

I am new to GIS and QGIS, and I am trying to build a hazard map for a certain county. This map is to have certain data, most of which I have been able to successfully upload and style. One dataset, however, I cannot seem to upload without errors. The original file types for this set are .gdb and its derivatives, which QGIS does not seem to like. I have also tried converting them to shapefiles, but again they are either rejected as errors outright, or appear only as empty tables devoid of features.

Here is the dataset in question (bottom of the page):
https://frap.fire.ca.gov/mapping/gis-data/

Comment: It is an Image in file geodatabase. There is an online version here https://www.arcgis.com/apps/mapviewer/index.html?url=https://egis.fire.ca.gov/arcgis/rest/services/FRAP/WUI/ImageServer

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you are not able to open the .gdb files is because QGIS cannot open raster files that are stored in file geodatabases as far as I know.

You need to open the gdb in Arcgis (Map/Pro), export the raster as a geotiff and then you will be able to open the file in QGIS.

In case you do not have access to ArcGIS I converted the raster file for you. you can download from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DzKR-B28dFz3JqRSDrqSJbWXldtCnANP/view?usp=sharing). To access; download the entire .zip, extract, drop the .tif file in QGIS and it should show the map of the area.

Comment: That was kind of you to do the conversion.  Bravo!

Comment: Thank you for the conversion!! I will give it a go!